# For what reason Hashmap replaces old object with a new one in case of equal objects and hashcode?

Tags: java, hashmap

Recently on the interview I was asked the question:

> What will happen if we have two equal objects and we put them as
>   values using the same key? Will the first value be replaced or does
>   hashmap uses `equals()` for values in order to determine whether or not
>   the element already exists?

I answered that if element already present in the bucket than it won't be replaced nor duplicate element will be added.

However, I tried to code this and I see that it's not true. The old object will be replaced.

I have `User` entity(`randomId` is used to determine which object is currently in the HashMap):

```
class User {
    private String userInfo;
    private String randomId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

    public User(String userInfo) {
        this.userInfo = userInfo;
    }

    public String getRandomId() {
        return randomId;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        User user = (User) o;
        return Objects.equals(userInfo, user.userInfo);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(userInfo);
    }
}
```

Now I'm testing the code:

```
public class HashMapTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, User> userLogins = new HashMap<>();
        User user1 = new User("regular user");
        User user2 = new User("regular user");

        System.out.println(user1.getRandomId());
        System.out.println(user2.getRandomId());

        userLogins.put("login", user1);
        userLogins.put("login", user2);

        for(Map.Entry<String, User> entry : userLogins.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " | " + entry.getValue().getRandomId());
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

> 63d21f34-c58c-4c73-8ee3-975951faf491
>   9b493ee7-33f2-4f93-92ae-8b44cba6e7c3
>   login | 9b493ee7-33f2-4f93-92ae-8b44cba6e7c3

Can anyone explain why hashmap replaces old value? I thought that `hashcode & equals` contract implies that there shouldn't be difference between `user1` and `user2` objects. So, from my point of view, it's logical to check if an equal object already exists in the bucket and don't replace it.

Comment: how would you get the second value ? if you have same key

Comment: You specified the exact same key. I don't see the illogic or inconsistency.  If you said `int x = 3;  x = 4;` What would x be?

Comment: Because that's what it says in the Javadoc. The old object with that key is removed and returned, and the new one inserted. Nothing about checking for equal objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `Map.put()` javadoc states that :

> If the map previously contained a mapping for the key, the old value
>   is replaced by the specified value.

So `put()` doesn't matter of the actual value for an existing key, just it overwrites it with the new value.

> I thought that hashcode & equals contract implies that there shouldn't
>   be difference between user1 and user2 objects.

Yes but the javadoc of `Map.put()` doesn't say that it checks the equality of the value for existing mapping before effectively putting the value. 
**It is your guesswork**.

Comment: That's a circular argument. :-) "It replaces it because it replaces it" doesn't say *why*.

Comment: @T.J.CrowderNo it isn't. It is an argument from authority. In this case, the specification. Just Ike your own answer.

Comment: @EJP: It's both. I'm sure the OP isn't asking "why does the hashmap implementation do this" (for which the above would be a reasonable answer). They're asking why maps are designed that way. Or so it seems to me.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder In that case it would be opinion-based and off topic.

Comment: @EJP: Probably, yeah, barring some quote from whoever designed the Java collections...

Answer (score 4):

`HashMap<K,V>` uses `hashCode` and `equals` only on the key objects. It never compares its value objects, treating them as a data load.

This behavior is specified in the documentation:

> ```
> public V put(K key, V value)
> ```
>
> Associates the specified value with the specified key in this map. If the map previously contained a mapping for the key, the old value is replaced.

Note the return type of `put`. It's not `void`, it's `V`, because when a value gets replaced with a new value, you get the old one back:

```
User old1 = userLogins.put("login", user1);
User old2 = userLogins.put("login", user2);
```

Above, `old1` would be `null`, while `old2` would be `user1`:

```
System.out.println(old2.getRandomId());
```

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation for `put` says](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#put-K-V-):

> Associates the specified value with the specified key in this map (optional operation). **If the map previously contained a mapping for the key, the old value is replaced by the specified value**. (A map m is said to contain a mapping for a key k if and only if m.containsKey(k) would return true.)

*(my emphasis)*

Note that it says nothing about checking whether the *value* equals anything, nor should it. The coder has expressly called `put`, saying "Put this value in the map under this key." It's not for the map to second-guess the programmer writing that code. It would also be unnecessary overhead.

There can be all kinds of reasons a coder wants to have a specific object, not just an equivalent one, in the map. Canonical caching (à la `String#intern`) is probably the first that comes to mind.

Comment: In what way is this not another 'circular argument'?

Comment: @EJP: I cite at least two, arguably three, reasons why it would be designed this way. I'm not just saying "it is because it is."

Comment: They all amount to reiterating what it says in the specification. I don't have a problem with that. I'm just wondering why you do.

Comment: @EJP: No, they aren't just reiterations.

Comment: They are really. An implementation that behaved as the OP suggests wouldn't comply with the specification. That's the only reason an implementor needs not to do it.

Answer (score 1):

If you did it this way, there's no confusion; so why would a `HashMap` (or any `Map`) be different?

```
   User user1 = new User("regular user");
   User user2 = new User("regular user");

   User login = user1;
   login = user2;
```

You used the exact same key each time. There can only be one value for a key in a `HashMap`.

The [javadoc for Map.put()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#put(K,%20V)) says that the method:

> Returns:
>   the previous value associated with key, or null if there was no mapping for key.

So actually, you could write this:

```
userLogins.put("login", user1);
User oldvalue = userLogins.put("login", user2);
assert(oldvalue == user1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Map designed to work with key-value basis. Meaning that, at any point of time, key have only one value and if you keep adding the value with same key, that value gets overridden for the provided key.

Nothing to do with the value's. Just `key` is the thing here.

You just used the same key twice and earlier one replaced with new value. That is what exactly how map should work.

Answer (score 0):

When asking why, one should consider the alternatives. The alternatives I see are either to silently ignore the second put or to throw an exception. I suggest the actual behavior is much better.

A basic assumption of the question is wrong:

> I thought that hashcode & equals contract implies that there shouldn't
>   be difference between user1 and user2 objects.

Neither `hashcode` not `equals` require that the object be identical. The [hashcode contract](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) specifically does not preclude different objects having the same hash:

> It is not required
>   that if two objects are unequal according to the
>   equals(java.lang.Object) method, then calling the hashCode method on
>   each of the two objects must produce distinct integer results.

Regarding `equals`, the objects in the example are not equal, but even if the `equals` were not to compare the userInfo, making them equal, the `equals` would be valid.